# MappingException: Doctrine is trying to catch my Entities in another module

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework3

I'm developing my first project with zend framework 3 (I've never develop with zend framework 2) and also using doctrine for the first time.

I was able to develop a first module called "Login" and now I'm making a second module called "Insumo".

The struct is like that:

module/
    Login/
    Insumo/
        src/
            Controller/
                ConfiguracaoController.php
            Entity/
                TbdInsumoConfiguracao.php

In ConfiguracaoController, my index function is like that:

```
public function indexAction() {
    $configuracao = $this->entityManagerDbOp->getRepository( TbdInsumoConfiguracao::class )->findOneById( 1 );

    return new ViewModel([
        'configuracao' => $configuracao
    ]);
}
```

In Login's module.config.php there are nothing related to "insumo" or "configuracao", but when I try to access my ConfiguracaoController's index method I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blMsc.png) error

If I try to access without the database code, it access the view normaly

What could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed at the configuration.
In Login's module I've config two connection orm_db_op and orm_db_sgf, but in Insumo I didn't config, so when I tried to use those connections, Doctrine searched for them in Login's module